# File upload only working on first component in v-for

Tags: file-upload, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

I have a component that uses a `v-for` to display a list of open jobs, in the component there is a FileUpload component that gets added to every listing as well. For some reason only the first job in the list will actually upload the file.

When submitting the files the first one's response is a json with all the correct data, all other listing's responses are just `true`.

I also noticed a difference in the request payload

First listing's request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryYRQqeeEwyNhW5hPy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="test resume.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Other listing's request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCwisfY5DcuxtoI7G
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"

null
```

Here are the components (built using Vuetify)
Main component:

```
<template>
  <div id="careers-page" >
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-expansion-panel>
          <v-expansion-panel-content  v-for="job in jobs" :key="job._id">
            <div slot="header">
              <span>{{ job.Position }}</span>
            </div>
            <v-card>
              <v-layout row wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 md6>
                  <v-card-text>{{ job.Description }}</v-card-text>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 md6>
                  <v-form v-model="valid" ref="form" lazy-validation>
                    <v-layout row>
                      <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>
                        <v-text-field label="Name" v-model="form.name" />
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row>
                      <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>
                        <v-text-field label="Email" v-model="form.email" />
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row>
                      <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>
                        <v-text-field label="Phone" v-model="form.phone" />
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                    <v-layout row>
                      <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>
                        <v-text-field multi-line label="Cover Letter" v-model="form.coverLetter" />
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                      <v-layout row wrap align-center>
                        <v-flex xs12 sm4 text-xs-center text-sm-right>
                          <v-btn class="anm-btn bold" @click="submit(job.Position, job._id)" color="ANMsecondary" dark depressed>Submit</v-btn>
                        </v-flex>
                        <v-flex xs12 sm4 text-xs-center text-sm-left>
                          <FileUpload :job="job" ref="uploadFile" />
                        </v-flex>
                      </v-layout>
                  </v-form>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-card>
          </v-expansion-panel-content>
        </v-expansion-panel>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import FileUpload from './FileUpload'

export default {
  components: {
    FileUpload
  },
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        name: null,
        email: null,
        phone: null,
        coverLetter: ''
      },
      valid: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      jobs: 'jobs'
    })
  },
  methods: {
    submit (position, jobId) {
      if (this.$refs.form[0].validate()) {
        this.$store.dispatch('submitApplication', {
          Name: this.form.name,
          Email: this.form.email,
          Phone: this.form.phone,
          Position: position,
          CoverLetter: this.form.coverLetter
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.$refs.uploadFile[0].submitFile(res.data.id)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

File upload component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
      <input type="file" ref="file" :id="job._id" class="inputfile" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()" />
      <label :for="job._id">Add Resume</label>
      <br>
      <span v-if="file" >
        {{ file.name }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      file: null
    }
  },
  props: ['job'],
  methods: {
    submitFile (refId) {
      let formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('files', this.file)
      formData.append('refId', refId)
      formData.append('field', 'Resume')
      formData.append('ref', 'application')
      this.$store.dispatch('uploadFile', formData)
        .then(() => {
          this.file = null
        })
    },
    handleFileUpload () {
      this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code for us to view and not just the output please?

Comment: @John I added the components.

Comment: try this: change `v-for="job in jobs"` to `v-for="(job, index) in jobs"`, change `submit(job.Position, job._id)` to `submit(job.Position, job._id, index)`, then in function=submit, replace `this.$refs.form[0]` with `this.$refs.form[index]`

Comment: @Sphinx that didn't work, still no file upload and the response is still the same

Comment: you should change `this.$refs.uploadFile[0]` to `this.$refs.uploadFile[index]` also

Comment: @Sphinx YOU ARE A GOD. I've been stuck on this for far too long. Thank you very much. Also, I don't think I can vote your answer as top post if it's in the comments so you might need to move it to an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your codes is use `this.$refs.form[0]` and `this.$refs.uploadFile[0]`. That causes always get the first ref of `this.$refs.form` and `this.$refs.uploadFile`.

As [Vue Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) said:

> When used on elements/components with v-for, the registered reference
> will be an Array containing DOM nodes or component instances.

So you should use one index to get the correct ref from the **Ref Array**.

So update your codes as below then should work.

1. change `v-for="job in jobs"` to `v-for="(job, index) in jobs"`
2. change `submit(job.Position, job._id)` to `submit(job.Position, job._id, index)`
3. in function=submit, replace `this.$refs.form[0]` with `this.$refs.form[index]` and change `this.$refs.uploadFile[0]` to `this.$refs.uploadFile[index]`